# Why does `local x` inside a zsh for loop output `x=y`?

Tags: shell, zsh

Given

```
for v in a b c; do
  local y
  y=$v
done
```

Zsh outputs the following automatically:

```
y=a
y=b
```

Why does this occur? What is the use? It wont output `y=c`, so it's not reliably `eval`'able but there must be a reason for this behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `zshbuiltins(1)` manpage, we have

- `local` -> "Same as `typeset` ..."
- `typeset` -> ...

  > If the shell option `TYPESET_SILENT` is not set, for each remaining name that refers to a parameter **that is already set**, the name and value of the parameter are printed in the form of an assignment.  Nothing is printed for newly-created parameters, or when any attribute flags listed below are given along with the name.

It appears for the iteration where v=b and v=c, `local y` is reporting on the value of y set in the *previous iteration*.

I'm not a zsh expert, but if it's like bash, then there are only 2 variable scopes: global and function-local. There is no concept of a variable local to a loop.

You should

- take `local y` out of the loop so it does not get executed needlessly repeatedly, or
- set the aforementioned shell option to make local shut up: `setopt TYPESET_SILENT`